# Uniquely Decodeable Codes

Tags: algorithm, compression

I am new to Data compression algorithms. I am trying to solve whether {bb,bbb,aa} is uniquely decodeable or now? I really need a head start or some initial help about how to start looking into this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  bbbbb could be bb, bbb or it could be bbb, bb.

Comment: Thanks. And b) {b,ba,bba,bbb} is not uniquely decodeable since bba .Am I right?